# PHP MySql URL Rewrite String Special character as a parameter issue

Tags: php, mysql, parameters, url-rewriting, slim

I am using slim-framework for api development. when i added any special character as String i am getting error page not found.

for example 
this get method

http://www.mydomain.com/REST-API/getHint/bol?/

bol? is string

when i add ? (Question Mark) to string then i got page not found error when i removed then it's ok,

where is the problem .. ? and how can i use the string with special character as parameter.

Thanks Advance

Comment: you realize that `?` is a url meta character, indicating the "end of the url" and "start of the query string"? If you want a literal `?` to be included as parameter, you'll have to embed it in urlencoded format, `%3F`.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by @Marc B url encoded format, %3F for ?  it solved my issue.

Thanks to @MarcB